# Is it possible to deprecate and subsequently remove a public attribute of a Lightning Web Component in a managed package?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, package, deprecation, packaging

For example, with this following snippet, if I wanted to remove the property from the package, what would be possible to do?

```xml
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets=“lightning__RecordPage”>
        <property name=“theOldProperty” type=“String” label=“Property Name (deprecated)”/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove those public properties (enabled with `@api` decorator) provided you have released a Managed package with `isExposed = false`

Once you have isExposed=true and the component is in the package, you cannot modify a public attribute. This is by design as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_packaging_add).

Quotes from docs

> If isExposed is false, the package developer can remove configuration targets and a public (@api) property from a component.

You can vote for the idea [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PeNNQA0).